# List it or List this

Tags: traducción

Me gustaría saber cómo podría traducirse `Lístalo`. He pensando en `List it` y en `List this` pero no estoy seguro de cuál es la correcta (si acaso alguna lo es).

Comment: Algo de contexto?

Comment: Bueno, sería para el nombre de una aplicación web ... algo así como: el usuario introduce un párrafo y la aplicación devuelve la lista de sentencias dentro del párrafo. Luego la aplicación "lista" el párrafo ... y por eso el nombre de "Lístalo".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because consiste en traducir un concepto al inglés. Este sitio es para consultas sobre el español, no para consultas en español sobre el inglés.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues literalmente se traduce como **list it**. Pero para el nombre de una aplicación también podría ser **list this**; eso me parece más natural para un nombre.

Si tenía un botón con el texto "listalo" no se podría traducir como "list this"; tendría que ser "list it". O en el caso específico que describes, sería mejor "list sentences" para un botón.

Comment: Creo que optaré por `List it`. Gracias